# What is the probability that a king who has 2 siblings has both sisters?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The king comes from a family of 3 children. What is the probability that both
the other children are his sisters? Solve the question with two methods i) by finding the
reduced sample space and ii) by using the definition of conditional probability.

I tried this question and got the answer 1/4. I used the reduced sample space where at least 1 child a boy (2 * 2 * 1). And the outcome where only 1 child is a boy being 1 * 1 * 1 giving 1/4.

Comment: If you are making the assumption that each child is a boy or girl with probability $\frac 12$, independent of all other children, then the answer is correct, though I don't really follow the reasoning.  Under the assumptions I mentioned, there are two siblings each of which is a girl with probability $\frac 12$ and $\frac 12\times \frac 12=\frac 14$.

Comment: This reminds me of the boy or girl paradox. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox

Comment: The problem is that our hero is a King. And we don't know the rule to design the new monarch in your country. For example, the rule can be : when the previous monarch dies, the new monarch is the oldest male child. It has existed in some countries. In this case, if I am the King, and my 2 siblings are older than me, so, necessary, they are girls. It impacts the probability that the 2 other children are both girls.  If we change the question and replace king by any other word, the answers are correct.

Comment: @Lourrran thank u